# Running the same query over a range of values

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables, People, Membership, and Clubs. I want to find out which 5 year period has had the most number of sign-ups. From what I'm hearing there are no FOR loops in SQL server 2012 so how can I do this? Thanks. Something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Membership
WHERE Membership.date>=x-01-01
AND Membership.date<x+10-12-31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a FOR loop with `WHILE` and `CURSOR` in SQL Server. But it has crazy overhead compared to Oracle's `FOR`. But almost anytime you think about using loop in SQL Server you are doing it wrong.

Your problem can be solved by a recursive CTE and a join:

```
;WITH Periods AS (
    SELECT  CAST('2000-01-01' AS Date) AS StartDate,
            CAST('2004-12-31' AS Date) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(year,1,StartDate),
            DATEADD(year,1,EndDate)
    FROM    Periods
    WHERE   StartDate < '2014-01-01'
)

SELECT  p.StartDate,
        p.EndDate,
        COUNT(m.*)
FROM    Memberships m
INNER JOIN Periods  p ON m.Date BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate
GROUP BY p.StartDate, p.EndDate
```

The `WITH` statement defines a recursive CTE containing 5-year periods for each year between 2000 and 2014. Adjust it as needed.